# Issues with node - Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

Tags: node.js

One of our devs is trying to run a script with node, but it gives this error output:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
Require stack: ...
```

Since this dev is new to node, and so do i, what exactly can we do?

We have node 12 running

Comment: Have you installed node modules in functions directory?

Comment: No, i believe, how can we do that? Thank you for your response

Comment: you can try: cd functions && npm install

Comment: Where is this functions directory?

Comment: where you put the functions directory in your project

Comment: My dev tells me he has /root/node_modules/firebase-functions
Could it work there?

Comment: It's functions folder in your project. Have you got it? it is generated when you setup firebase for your project. If not, you should check the setup instructions again